# How do I fetch all relation objects in Parse.com IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following query:

```
PFObject *photoData = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photos"];
PFRelation *relation = [photoData relationForKey:@"photo"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"People"];
query = [relation query];
[query whereKey:@"deleted" equalTo:@NO];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" lessThan:_createdAt];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
query.limit = 20;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    ...
}
```

I have a database table in Parse called `People`. In that table, there is a bunch of data but has a relation called `photo`. Now, I am saving one photo (with its data) in the photo relation. In the Parse dashboard, the data is saved correctly.

How do I fetch that back? Right now I have constraints on this system (and question) that each `People` objects has ONLY one photo object. So I need to fetch it all back at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Relation` is just what its literal meaning is. It does not contain any data. If you want to query the data, you need to get the `PFQuery` from `PFRelation` by `query` method like so:

```
PFRelation *relation = [photoData relationForKey:@"photo"];
PFQuery *photoQuery = [relation query];
// perform your photoQuery here
```

If you limit them by one object only, then you can change your `photo` as `Pointer` type instead of using `Relation`.